# Automatically restore last session in Gvim

Tags: session, vim

I installed sessionman, and it works fine. But I lose session when reload the X session twice (logout/login, reboot, etc), because when KDE restores Gvim, it does not load session automatically, but only last file, and then saves this under the last session name on next reload. If I did not run SessionOpen then on next reload my last session is lost.

I configured session autosave already. It would be nice if Gvim can load last session automatically too. However, this feature does not work for me even manually. When I restart Gvim, SessionShowLast prints "Last session is undefined, current session is """.

The sessionman documentation says: "The name of an opened session is saved in g:LAST_SESSION variable which is saved in the viminfo file if 'viminfo' option contains '!'". But I have not found any clear explanation what is "viminfo option", where it should contain '!', and how do I set it. Also I'm not sure how to execute SessionOpenLast from vimrc.

If the way I'm trying to fix the problem is wrong then please correct me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`viminfo` is a variable that describes what data should be stored in the `viminfo` file.

For full details, run `:help 'viminfo'` (note the quotes) in `vim`:

```
    !       When included, save and restore global variables that start
            with an uppercase letter, and don't contain a lowercase
            letter.  Thus "KEEPTHIS and "K_L_M" are stored, but "KeepThis"
            and "_K_L_M" are not.  Nested List and Dict items may not be
            read back correctly, you end up with a string representation
            instead.
```

Use `:set viminfo` to see the current value of your `viminfo` setting. Modify it in your `~/.vimrc` file.

```
set viminfo='100,<500,s10,h,!
```

Because `vimrc` is loaded before plugins, adding `SessionOpenLast` to `vimrc` will not work. To solve this, create an auto-command:

```
autocmd VimEnter * SessionOpenLast
```

Comment: The quotes in ":help 'viminfo'" command is what I really missed! Thanks ))

Comment: I Added "!" to default value "'100,<500,s10,h" (for linux) in vimrc:
set viminfo='100,<500,s10,h,!
And it works.
Now looking for the way to run SessionOpenLast from vimrc.

Comment: I don't know anything about the `sessionman` plugin, but are you lucky enough to just add `SessionOpenLast` to the end of your vimrc?

Comment: Error detected while processing /home/artem/.vimrc:
line  114:
E492: Not an editor command:     SessionOpenLast

Comment: Nice! I suggest adding it as an answer so you can mark it Accepted, so someone else in the future can find it that much more easily.

Comment: The problem is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821033/vim-how-to-run-a-command-immediately-when-starting-vim/6821698#6821698)

Comment: Done. You probably should accept the changes to make them visible to all.

Comment: Did you edit my answer? If you did, it looks like it didn't survive the edit suggestion moderation queue. (Which does mean a duplication of work to re-write it...) But I actually meant for you to write your own new answer here with full details -- it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4473/discussion-between-raacer-and-sarnold)

Answer (score 1):

```
  "My Sessionman Conf
  set viminfo='100,<500,s10,h,!
  let sessionman_save_on_exit = 1

  function! ReadSession()
  SessionOpenLast
  endfunction

  " if no file args then open the last session
  autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 | call ReadSession() | endif
```

Comment: could you please explain also a little so that others can easily understand