# How start WindowManager in VIM at startup

Tags: vim

How can I configure VIM to automatically open WindowManager at startup? That is, how can I configure it to execute :WMToggle at startup?

Comment: how to close vim when all files are closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this related question: [Vim - how to run a command immediately when starting vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821033/vim-how-to-run-a-command-immediately-when-starting-vim).

For what you are dong I think the second solution is the easy way to do what you want.

You will just need to put this in your .vimrc:

```
autocmd VimEnter * WMToggle
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an alias in your `~/.bashrc` or wherever you put that kind of things:

```
alias vim='/path/to/vim -c :WMToggle'
```