# How to invoke a plugin in vim when no file is opened from commandline?

Tags: vim

I tried suggestions in this question: [Vim - how to run a command immediately when starting vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821033/vim-how-to-run-a-command-immediately-when-starting-vim)

command gets executed everytime vim is invoked,

I want MRU plugin to be opened only when I'm invoking vim without any files to open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you can do something like this:

```
if argc() == 0
    augroup MyVimEnter
     au!
     au VimEnter * ... " put the plugin command here
    augroup END
endif
```

Comment: Without any files would be `argc() == 0`, but otherwise a fine solution!