# Why won't vim recognise a plugin command in the vimrc, but it will recognise it when running?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, pathogen

I've installed the [vim-gitgutter plugin](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) with pathogen.
I can type `:GitGutterLineHighlightsEnable` from inside vim and line highlights are turned on, great.

But I want line highlights to be automatically enabled at startup, so I added the command to my `~/.vimrc`. However when I start vim, I get "E492: Not an editor command: GitGutterLineHighlightsEnable". Once vim has started up, I can run the command.

My vimrc looks like this:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
colorscheme railscasts

  .. snip tabs and colors etc ..

GitGutterLineHighlightsEnable
hi GitGutterAddLine guibg=#222F22
hi GitGutterChangeLine guibg=#222239
hi GitGutterDeleteLine guibg=#2F2222
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you determined yourself, plugins are processed after the .vimrc.

What you can do if you don't like using a VimEnter autocmd, is put a file in your ~/.vim/after/plugin directory for any commands that should run after plugins are loaded.

Answer (score 9):

Figured it out.

.vimrc is executed **before** plugins are loaded. From [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821033/vim-how-to-run-a-command-immediately-when-starting-vim), I changed the commands to:

```
autocmd VimEnter * GitGutterLineHighlightsEnable
```

This executes the command after vim has started up.

Answer (score 7):

Use

`let g:gitgutter_highlight_lines = 1`

instead of

`GitGutterLineHighlightsEnable`