# How can I run a normal command after scripts load?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to start vim from command line and have it jump to a certain place in the file and run `<c-c>g` to trigger goto_definition in python-mode.

So far running `vim filename "+call cursor(x, y)"` does at least get me to the position I want, but now how do I run `<c-c>g` afterwards?

If I try `vim % "+call cursor(x, y)" -c "normal! <c-c>g"` I get a "not an editor command" error

Answer (score 1):

Try

`vim FILENAME -c "call cursor(x, y)" -c "call pymode#rope#goto_definition()"`

`<c-c>g` is actually bind to function `pymode#rope#goto_definition()`.
You can look up in `:map` to see the mapping.

Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821033/vim-how-to-run-a-command-immediately-when-starting-vim) if you're interested in why `not an editor command` error occured.

Comment: Interestingly that still fails, but the logic is sound. It should work. The exact command that I ran is `:!gvim main.py -c "call cursor(41, 45)" -c "call pymode#rope#goto_definition()"` which spits out an error about parenthesis. I'm guessing that pymode isn't fully "warmed up" at the point that gets called

Comment: This is my exact error (wouldn't let me copy it out of gvim) https://i.imgur.com/L7q0RE8.png

Comment: Why do you add `:!` before gvim? Isn't it a normal terminal command instead of a vim command? Sorry, I'm not familiar with windows environment. Which version is your vim?